# What is the name of this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

This plant was found growing in Germany. I have never seen it before, reverse Google image search did not help either. Can you help me identify what type of plant this is?

[image: Full view]
[image: Flower]
[image: Root]

Thanks, looks like it is something like this:

http://pflanzen-enzyklopaedie.eu/stauden/amerikanische-kermesbeere-phytolacca-americana/#more-4034

Related question:

https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries/2610#2610

Comment: Nice pictures! Thanks also for getting pictures of different plant parts.

Comment: Also see [similar question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries/2610#2610) on GL. (Highest voted three-word answer on the whole site.)

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to GL. As per this discussion on meta http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/151/plant-identification-questions

Comment: @PatrickB see this question: [Is it a good idea to have an identical topic (plant identification) on both GL and Biology?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236648/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-an-identical-topic-plant-identification-on-both-gl-a/236649#236649) I'm coming to the conclusion that plant identification questions can be asked on either site, but for different reasons.

Comment: technically these photos are very good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like some species of *Phytolacca* to me.

It's possibly *Phytolacca americana*, which is native to the US (in fact it's an enthusiastic 'volunteer' in my garden) but [naturalized in Europe](http://books.google.com/books?id=5vd_ZE7UDV8C&lpg=PA1018&ots=tmnF-2RlZr&dq=european%20phytolacca&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q=phytolacca&f=false).

If you still have any in the ground, once they ripen, the berries are intensely purple and [can be used as dye (or even eaten?)](http://www.efloras.org/florataxon.aspx?flora_id=1&taxon_id=220010427)

---

[Mark A. Nienaber & John W. Thieret. Phytolaccaceae.  In: Flora of North America Editorial Committee, eds.  1993+.  Flora of North America North of Mexico. New York and Oxford. (link goes to entry of P. americana)](http://www.efloras.org/florataxon.aspx?flora_id=1&taxon_id=220010427)

Comment: Seems like it is an invasive species that can prevent others from growing.

Comment: It certainly grows very weedily here!

Comment: Oreotrephes You have a garden, therefore you should get over to GL now and then. =)

Comment: It is a *Phytolacca*, but not *americana*, because the flowers stand upright. P. americana has hanging flowers.

Answer (score 1):

It is [Phytolacca acinosa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_acinosa) because the flowers grow upwards and the fruits are ribbed. [Phytolacca americana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana) has downward pointing flowers and smooth fruits.