# What is the name of this big plant with a purple trunk and green to purple berries?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I have photographed the following plant in our garden in Pittsburgh, PA.

Do you know the name of the plant?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: cf http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries/2610#2610

Comment: also cf http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/what-is-the-name-of-this-plant

Comment: So clearly we need to start pokeweedID.stackexchange.com, where the only correct answer to any question will be "Phytolacca"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plant looks like [Pokeweed (*Phytolacca americana*)](http://extension.umass.edu/landscape/weeds/phytolacca-americana) to me, a common "weed" in the U.S.

Comment: 3cat looks like you're right. I have to dig this up all the time, and it's not fun. Of course, being a professional horticulturist/arborist/landscaper means you want to never see this plant again, al least in beds. This is the fouth SE question asking for the id of this weed.